# Drag and droped Jtable Netbeans error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I created two tables by drag and drop on the form. These tables are intended to capture data from the user and submit to MySQL DB. The first table works 100% which is tblsales . But the second table which is tblrevenue gives me this error

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:"
```

I have been searching for a solution since yesterday no luck so far. Any help will be appreciated. 
below are my codes

```
         /// Insert into another tblcost_of_sell table 
         int costrows = tblsales.getRowCount();

         String  statementSell= ("INSERT INTO tblcost_of_sell(client_id,divisiuon,cposo_id,usercode,suplier_id,cost_of_account,quote_ref,invoice_ref,price,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ");

         PreparedStatement  statement2 = conn.prepareStatement(statementSell);

         for(int indexsales = 0; indexsales<=costrows;indexsales++){
         String tbldivisiuon= (String)tblsales.getValueAt(indexsales, 0);
         String tblcost_of_account = (String)tblsales.getValueAt(indexsales, 1);
         String tblsuplier_id = (String)tblsales.getValueAt(indexsales, 2);
         String tbldescription = (String)tblsales.getValueAt(indexsales, 3);
         String tblquote_ref = (String)tblsales.getValueAt(indexsales, 4);
         String tblprice = (String)tblsales.getValueAt(indexsales, 5);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         statement2.setString(1,"7");
         statement2.setString(2,tbldivisiuon);
          statement2.setString(3, Integer.toString(last_id)); //forein key 
          statement2.setString(4,"1000");
         statement2.setString(5,tblsuplier_id);
           statement2.setString(6,tblcost_of_account);
           statement2.setString(7,tblquote_ref);
           statement2.setString(8,"Wedelete");
           statement2.setString(9,tblprice);
           statement2.setString(10,tbldescription);

statement2.executeUpdate();
statement2.addBatch();

         }
statement2.executeBatch();
statement2.close();
         // insert into tblcost_of_sell ends here 

                  int rowsRevenue = tblrevenue.getRowCount();
String  StatementRev = ("INSERT INTO  tblrevenue(client_id , divisiuon,usercode,cposo_id,rev_account,qunatity,unit_price,total_price,description)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
PreparedStatement     Statement3 = conn.prepareStatement(StatementRev);

for(int i= 0; i< rowsRevenue; i++){

   // tblrevenue.removeRow(this);
                  String itdivisiuon = (String)tblrevenue.getValueAt(i, 0);
                  String itrev_account  = (String)tblrevenue.getValueAt(i, 1);
                  String  itdescription = (String)tblrevenue.getValueAt(i, 2);
                  String   itqunatity = (String)tblrevenue.getValueAt(i, 3);
                  String  itunit_price  = (String)tblrevenue.getValueAt(i, 4);
                  String   ittotal_price  = (String)tblrevenue.getValueAt(i, 5);


//Insert into the Third table
Statement3.setString(1,"7");
Statement3.setString(2,itdivisiuon);
Statement3.setString(3,"1000");
Statement3.setString(4, Integer.toString(last_id)); //forein key 
Statement3.setString(5,itrev_account);
Statement3.setString(6,itqunatity);
Statement3.setString(7,itunit_price);
Statement3.setString(8,ittotal_price);
Statement3.setString(9,itdescription);


Statement3.executeUpdate();
Statement3.addBatch();

                  }
```

Comment: *"Any help will be appreciated."* Any question any time soon? And by 'soon' I mean before 4 more close votes.)

Comment: We can't possibly help you with the information provided. So, the error message tells you the line causing the problem. So look at that line, figure out which index is wrong and fix the index. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of the variables are correct but some are not. Be consistent!!!

Comment: Great but look the same code for the working table is the one I used on the second one , they both have the same number of columns , only variables change . but if I delete one of the two the other works . They cant just seem to work together .